# How to find unique field values from two columns in data frame

Tags: r, unique

I have a data frame containing many columns, including `Quarter` and `CustomerID`. In this I want to identify the unique combinations of `Quarter` and `CustomerID`.

For eg:

```
masterdf <- read.csv(text = "
    Quarter,  CustomerID, ProductID
    2009 Q1,    1234,     1
    2009 Q1,    1234,     2
    2009 Q2,    1324,     3
    2009 Q3,    1234,     4
    2009 Q3,    1234,     5
    2009 Q3,    8764,     6
    2009 Q4,    5432,     7")
```

What i want is:

```
FilterQuarter     UniqueCustomerID
2009 Q1           1234
2009 Q2           1324
2009 Q3           8764
2009 Q3           1234
2009 Q4           5432
```

How to do this in R? I tried `unique` function but it is not working as i want.

Comment: It looks like he wants the unique `(Quarter, CustomerID)` pairs. However, it's unclear how he would want to column-bind this new data with a possibly differently-dimensioned data frame.

Comment: I want both two columns with there unique value ie if the CustomerID 1234 present in 2009 Q3 it should come. but if i used unique it will take only 2009 Q1.

Comment: I have edited here 2009 Q1 and 2009 Q3 both have CustomerID 1234 so if i used unique function it is taking only one time i want it should come both 2009 Q1 and 2009 Q3 . thank you for your fast response.

Comment: How do you apply your `unique` function? I keep on asking this...

Comment: See Arun v <- c[(1,1,2)] unique(v) gives output as 1,2 ok. In above question the CustomerID 1234 have appeared in quarters 2009 Q1 and Q3. 1234 has appeared twice in 2009 Q1, in my output i want it to appear only once. similarly in 2009 Q3 it has appeared twice, here also in my output i want it to appear only once. The CustomerID may have appeared multiple times in a single quarter but i want to print it only once. How to do this in R.

Comment: What does `v <- c[(1,1,2)]` mean? that is not valid `R`.

Comment: What i tried is  unique(masterdf$Quarter,masterdf$Customer.Id) for this output is 
 [1] "2009 Q1" "2009 Q2" "2011 Q1" "2010 Q2" "2010 Q4" "2012 Q1" "2009 Q3"
 [8] "2010 Q1" "2011 Q3" "2009 Q4" "2010 Q3" "2011 Q4" "2011 Q2" "2012 Q2"
[15] "NA QNA"

Comment: what about `unique(masterdf)`

Comment: In masterdf it contain nearly 16 columns one of them is ProductId column.what happen if i do unique(masterdf) is it will take if same customerId has two different productId then it is repeateding.

Comment: What about `duplicated(my.df[c("FilterQuarter", "UniqueCustomerID")])`?

Comment: When i tried above command, i got duplicated(my.df[c("FilterQuarter", "UniqueCustomerID")])                       Error in `[.data.frame`(my.df, c("FilterQuarter", "UniqueCustomerID")) : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: @user2492230 please try to extend what commenters have told you yourself. You are waiting to be spoon-fed the right answer. The error above is because you have no columns in your dataframe (yet) called `"FilterQuarter"`. Your data.frame is also not called `"my.df"` so I don't know why you would type that. Your `data.frame` is called `"masterdf"`

Comment: i tried masterdf only. not my .df . sorry for that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The long comments under the OP are getting hard to follow. You are looking for `duplicated` as pointed out by **@RomanLustrik**. Use it to subset your original `data.frame` like this...

```
masterdf[ ! duplicated( masterdf[ c("Quarter" , "CustomerID") ] ) , ]
#  Quarter CustomerID
#1 2009 Q1       1234
#3 2009 Q2       1324
#4 2009 Q3       1234
#6 2009 Q3       8764
#7 2009 Q4       5432
```

Comment: Thank you i got the output as i wanted,with help of your command  @SimonO101.

Comment: @user2492230 you are welcome. I am glad we could sort this out!

Answer (score 2):

Another simple way is to use `SQL` queries from R, check the codes below. 
This assumes masterdf is the name of the original file...

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select Quarter, CustomerID from masterdf group by 1,2")
```